# ¿Cómo validar que sea un correo valido y específico en CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, validación, codeigniter-3

Estoy utilizando la `librería "form_validation"` del `Framework CodeIgniter`, y necesito que el `e-mail` con el que los usuarios que se registran tengan en común el mismo `dominio` de correo.

Ejemplo:

> correo1@mi_dominio.com
>
> correo2@mi_dominio.com

En pocas palabras, que solamente se puedan registrar usuarios con los `dominios` especificados.

De esta manera estoy validando actualmente los `e-mail`, pero se puede registrar con cualquier correo, y es lo que quiero evitar:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('correo', 'correo electrónico', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[usuarios.correo]');
```

No sé si exista alguna manera en la que esa función se pueda integrar a esa validación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Callbacks y Callables

CodeIgniter por fortuna [sí implementa este tipo de validaciones personalizadas](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods), solamente se agrega a la definición de reglas y puede ser arreglo tanto como de un solo string, simplemente cambia la manera en que se llaman:

Ejemplo usando callback:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('correo', 'correo electrónico', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[usuarios.correo]|callback_checar_dominio');

//esta funcion ocupa estar dentro del controlador al nivel de las otras funciones
function checar_dominio($str) {
    return TRUE; //aquí se validaría el dominio, regresa valor booleano
}
```

Ejemplo usando callable:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('correo', 'correo electrónico', 
    array(
        'required',
        'trim',
        'valid_email',
        'is_unique[usuarios.correo]',
        function checar_dominio($str) {
            return TRUE; //aquí se validaría el dominio, regresa valor booleano
        }
    )
);
```